# How to show content of section and display it when click menu

Tags: javascript, html

I write 4 sections pages in index html page and i want link the sections page with the menu.

How can I show the content of section when click at each menu?

I use ready website from bootstrap and edit it and I use atom program.

What i should to write at page html or at javascript?

Below is my code:

[image: this the menu at header in the body]

Comment: Please don't give images of your source code. Stackoverflow allows you to include code snippets which makes it much easier for myself and others to work with and help find a solution to your problem but I would also recommend you show what you have tried so far. Stackoverflow is **not** a free programming service.

Comment: I wish I could get paid for all the job im doing here but so far I try to respond 1 question for each answer I get

Comment: Also when you say *"how to show content of section when click at each menu"* Do you mean scroll to that `section` or do you mean all sections are hidden/not visible and only want to make it visible when clicked? If all sections are visible then you can always set the anchor tags within the navigation menu to target the `ID` of that section as shown in this [**JsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/8p4xu0f9/)

Comment: @JeanBelmont but you haven't submitted any questions....

Comment: @NewToJS I have more than 1 account lol :P and sometimes i forget to swap between them

Answer (score 0):

I concur with NewtoJS you should post a code snippet instead of an image, and you are asking at least 3 questions any way I will try to help

1.-  I want link the sections page with the menu?
you can do so using The HTML **< a>** tag that defines a hyperlink, which is used to link from one page to another.

2.- how to show content of section when click at each menu?
this can have many different aproaches but since you tagged the question with html I will try to answer acordingly. **Each section should have its own html file, or and "ID" if they are in the same page** when you click on a **< a>** tag refering to that page or "ID" it will lead to that section.

3.- what i should to write at page html or at javascript ?
of course a web site can be done without using Javascript it is easy but you need to use CSS as well for styling purposes. Generally you can't choose just one, you have to use both and depending on your needs could be more from one than the other. please refer to [this site](https://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp) for a complete documentation on HTML 
and you can read about javascript [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp), if you want to learn CSS please refer to [this page.](https://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp)

a side comment:

> for a complete documentation on how to use html **< a>** tags please refer to [this >site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)

I will suget not to use POOPSTRAP, and you should try to work with wordpress or something like that if you dont know how to code, and if you want to learn to code starting in stackoverflow is a bad aproach, you should first take a free course on udemy.

Comment: This should be posted as a comment since this does not solve of answer the question.

Comment: they do, obviously the guy who posted the question does not speak english but I understood what he meant.

Comment: I don't believe the question is clear enough to submit a solution. The `section` tags in question could be all in one page but your suggestion is assuming new page navigation.

Comment: if  the section tag in question is in the same page and you put an ID inside the < a> tag it will move the page to the section so my answer is correct. But i got your point so will change my answer to point that out

Comment: I would be more clear about how to target the `section` element `ID`'s with the `a`nchor tags. At least you are explaining the steps/use of that rather than assuming the OP already knows  how to make a anchor tag target `DOM` element `ID`'s

Comment: for a complete documentation on how to use html a tags please refer to this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) site.